# Evaluating $\int\frac{2x}{x^2+1}\mathrm dx$ before learning substitution

Tags: calculus, integration

**Context**

This is a problem in my friend's textbook. The course covers basic calculus, with an introduction to limits, derivatives and integrals. This is important, because when I say "solve this integral without using substitution", I mean *before learning* substitution. Otherwise, one might be tempted to use *more* advanced tools (like integrating the Taylor expansion instead), rather than less.

**Problem**

> Evaluate $\displaystyle\int\frac{2x}{x^2+1}\mathrm dx$

**Caveat**

Being that this is before the chapter teaching the substitution method, they seem to be hinting at some method of solving this even more basic than that.

**My thoughts so far**

There was a problem in an earlier chapter, namely to evaluate $\displaystyle\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\ln(x^2+1)$, and lo!

So the only method I can think of, that is even basic-er than substitution, is to *remember* that you have differentiated this function before and *recall* that the integrand above is the result of that derivative.

...and then add $C$ (lest I forget, again).

**Question**

So, assuming the idea was NOT to simply recall and remember as if one has an eidetic memory, do you have any ideas on how this can be solved in a more basic fashion than using substitution? I'm at a loss.

Comment: I don't think there are any techniques that are more basic than substitution but less basic than inspection.

Comment: Before I learnt substitution, I just remembered $\displaystyle\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx} \ln (x) = \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$. I don't recall there being another way to integrate without substitution.

Comment: May be you stress out what you have learned so far. So that one can give an appropriate response to your inquiry

Comment: It would be what your thoughts were i.e. being aware of the derivative of $\ln (x^2 +1)$

Comment: Ultimately, _all_ integrals will eventually come to a form where you just "remember" that you've differentiated something before and gotten the integrand as a result. You can't really solve integrals with pen and paper without it. Exactly where you take that step is, of course, different from problem to problem, but I wouldn't be opposed to that technique on a general basis.

Answer (score 1):

Considering that your attention is drawn to the fact that the denominator is $D(x) = x^2 +1$, and that you have to solve 
$$
I = \int\frac{D'(x)}{D(x)}\mathrm dx
$$ 
Now you may have learnt by heart (or you may easily deduce) that for all integrals of this kind,  $I = \ln D(x) + C$. Hence you find that the solution is the logarithm of the denominator, plus an integration constant.

Now there's a matter of interpretation:

- have you substituted the denominator by a function,
- or have you exploited that you know that all integrals of the given kind have the solution $I = \ln D(x) + C$, and you realized that your integral **IS** of that given kind?